Prove r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s is a real number for real numbers r,s$\gt_{\Bbb R}$0.
One part of Exercise 2.8 in Classic Set Theory by Derek Goldrei is

Prove r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s is a real number for real numbers r,s$\gt_{\Bbb R}$0.

Some definitions from that book:

Definition of $\lt_{\Bbb Q}$

$\lt_{\Bbb Q}$ stand for the usual order on $\Bbb Q$.

Definition of real numbers

A Dedekind left set is a subset r of $\Bbb Q$ with the following properties:
(i)r is a proper, non-empty subset of $\Bbb Q$, so that $\emptyset \neq$ r $\neq \Bbb Q$;
(ii)r is 'closed to the left', i.e. if $q\in$r and $p\lt_{\Bbb Q}q$, then $p\in$r;
(iii)r has no maximum element, i.e. for any $p\in$ r there is some $q\in$ r with $p\lt_{\Bbb Q}q$.
A real numebr is a Dedekind left set and $\Bbb R$ is the set of all such real numbers.
Let $q\in \Bbb Q$. Then the real number corresponding to $q$ is q$=\{p\in \Bbb Q: p\lt_{\Bbb Q} q\}$.

Definition of $=_{\Bbb R},\gt_{\Bbb R},\ge_{\Bbb R},\lt_{\Bbb R},\le_{\Bbb R}$

Let r and s be Dedekind left sets.
Then r and s are equal, written as r$=_{\Bbb R}$s, if they are equal as sets, i.e. for all $q$, $q\in$ r if and only if $q\in$ s;
r is less than or equal to s, written as r$\le_{\Bbb R}$s, if r$\subseteq$s, i.e. for all $q$, if $q\in$ r then $q\in$ s;
r is less than s, written as r$\lt_{\Bbb R}$s, if r$\le_{\Bbb R}$s and r$\neq_{\Bbb R}$ s.

Definition of the product of $2$ real numbers

Let r,s$\in \Bbb R$. If r,s$\gt_{\Bbb R}$0, then the product of r and s is defined as
r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s=$\{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q: p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0\}\cup\{q\in \Bbb Q: q\le_{\Bbb Q}0\}$.
So in order to prove that r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s is a real number, we have to show that r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (i),(ii) and (iii). I have no trouble with (i) and (iii). However, I can't prove r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (ii).
My attempt:
Pick any $x\in \Bbb Q$. Supposes $x\lt_{\Bbb Q} y$ for some $y\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. If $x\le_{\Bbb Q}0$, then $x\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s by definition of r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. Suppose $x\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$, then $y=p\cdot q$ for some $p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$ and $q\in$ s, $q\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$.
I thought of defining $t$ by $t^2=_{\Bbb Q}\frac{pq}{x}$, which is similar to how I prove r$+_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (ii). Then we would have $x=_{\Bbb Q}\frac{p}{t}\frac{q}{t}$. Since $\frac{p}{t}\in$ r, $\frac{q}{t}\in$ s and $\frac{p}{t},\frac{q}{t}\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$, we would have $x\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. The problem is that $t$ is not necessarily a rational number, so the above proof doesn't work.
How can we prove r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (ii)?

We first show r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (i).
Clearly $0\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s so r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s$\neq \emptyset$. Since r is a real number, by (i), there exists a rational number $a\in \Bbb Q \setminus$r. By the argument in Exercise 2.2(a), $a$ is an upper bound of r. Since r$\gt_{\Bbb R}$0 (i.e. 0 is a proper subset of r), there exists some $c\in$ r with $c\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Since $a\gt_{\Bbb Q} c$, we have $a\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Similarly there exists $b\in \Bbb Q \setminus$s with $b\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. By property of $\Bbb Q$, $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$. We now show $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\in \Bbb Q\setminus$r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. Suppose $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. Since $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$, we must have $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\in\{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q: p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0\}$. Hence there exists some $p,q$ such that $p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b=p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q$. However, by property of $\Bbb Q$, $a\gt_{\Bbb Q}p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0,b\gt_{\Bbb Q}q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$, we have $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\gt_{\Bbb Q}p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q$, a contradiction. So $a\cdot_{\Bbb Q}b\in \Bbb Q\setminus$r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. Hence r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s$\neq \Bbb Q$.
We now show r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (ii).
Pick any $x\in \Bbb Q$. Supposes $x\lt_{\Bbb Q} y$ for some $y\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. If $x\le_{\Bbb Q}0$, then $x\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s by definition of r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s. Suppose $x\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$, then $y\in\{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q: p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0\}$. So $y=p\cdot_{\Bbb Q} q$ for some $p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$ and $q\in$ s, $q\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Define $m,n$ by $m=_{\Bbb Q}\frac{\frac{x}{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q}+_{\Bbb Q}1}{2}$ and $n=_{\Bbb Q}\frac{\frac{x}{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q}}{m}$ ($m\neq_{\Bbb Q}0$). Clearly $m,n\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$. From $x\lt_{\Bbb Q} y=_{\Bbb Q}p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q$, we have $\frac{x}{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q}\lt_{\Bbb Q} 1$. We may then deduce that $m\lt_{\Bbb Q}1$ and $n\lt_{\Bbb Q}1$. Now $m\cdot_{\Bbb Q}n=_{\Bbb Q}\frac{x}{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q}$. We have $x=_{\Bbb Q}(p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}m)\cdot_{\Bbb Q}(q\cdot_{\Bbb Q}n)$. Since $p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}m\lt_{\Bbb Q}p$, by (ii), $p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}m\in$ r. Similarly, $q\cdot_{\Bbb Q}n\in$ s. Clearly, $p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}m\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\cdot_{\Bbb Q}n\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$. So $x\in\{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q: p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0\}$. Therefore $x\in$r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s.
We now show r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s satisfy (iii).
Pick any $x\in \Bbb Q$. Suppose $x\le_{\Bbb Q}0$. Since r$\gt_{\Bbb R}$0, there exists some $c\in$r with $c\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Similarly, there exists some $d\in$s with $d\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Note that $c\cdot_{\Bbb Q}d\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s and, by property of $\Bbb Q$, we have $c\cdot_{\Bbb Q}d\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0\gt_{\Bbb Q} x$, which implies $c\cdot_{\Bbb Q}d\gt_{\Bbb Q} x$. Suppose $x\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$. Then $x\in\{p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q: p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q}0$ and $q\in$ s,$q\gt_{\Bbb Q}0\}$. So $x=p\cdot_{\Bbb Q} q$ for some $p\in$ r, $p\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$ and $q\in$ s, $q\gt_{\Bbb Q} 0$. Since $p\in$ r, there exists some $u\in$r with $p\lt_{\Bbb Q}u$. Similarly, there exists some $v\in$ s  with $q\lt_{\Bbb Q}v$. Since $0\lt_{\Bbb Q}p\lt_{\Bbb Q}u$ and $0\lt_{\Bbb Q}q\lt_{\Bbb Q}v$, by property of $\Bbb Q$, we have $p\cdot_{\Bbb Q}q\lt_{\Bbb Q}u\cdot_{\Bbb Q}v$. So $u\cdot_{\Bbb Q}v\in$ r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s and $x\lt_{\Bbb Q}u\cdot_{\Bbb Q}v$.
It follows that r$\cdot_{\Bbb R}$s is a real number.
